# How to use ALPN in Netty with OpenJDK 1.8.0_252

Tags: netty

I am trying to use ALPN in Netty with OpenJDK 1.8.0_252 and I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN$Provider
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JettyAlpnSslEngine.newServerEngine(JettyAlpnSslEngine.java:60)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$AlpnWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:141)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.configureAndWrapEngine(JdkSslContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.newEngine(JdkSslContext.java:330)
```

According to https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn-agent :

"Starting with OpenJDK 1.8.0_252 the use of jetty-alpn-agent is not strictly required anymore since the standard ALPN APIs have been backported to OpenJDK 1.8.0_252 from Java 9."

So it seems that the Jetty ALPN extensions shouldn't be necessary. Any thoughts on how to configure Netty so the Jetty ALPN agent isn't required when I know I am running on open JDK 1.8.0_252?

Answer (score 0):

It should "just work"... That said you need to at least use netty 4.1.49.Final as this was the release that contains the needed fix : https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10196

Comment: Thanks! I was using a just slightly too old Netty version ;)